# How to ensure that no data get lost while transferring them to and storing them on the server?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

JavaScript:

```
const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

function sendData(data) {
  XHR.open('POST', 'savedata.php');
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  XHR.send('data=' + JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    if (file_exists('data.json')) {
        $file = file_get_contents('data.json');
        $accumulatedData = json_decode($file);
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
        array_push($accumulatedData, $data);
        $encodedAccumulatedData = json_encode($accumulatedData);
        file_put_contents('data.json', $encodedAccumulatedData);
    }
}
```

If the intervals between the data transfers are very short, data get lost. How to prevent this?

Comment: What part of the upload are you worried about? Are you worried about transport errors because of temporary loss of network coverage?

Comment: I'm not worried, but I have actually noticed that there are some data objects that have not been stored in the JSON array. This does not happen with a timeout (e.g. 100 ms) between the data transfers. To be honest, I don't know if it is caused client-side or server-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a race condition, likely because multiple requests write to the same data.json file at the same time.

You should be able to prevent this by locking the file so only one PHP process has access to it at a time.

```php
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    if (file_exists('data.json')) {
        $fp = fopen("data.json", "r+");
        // acquire an exclusive lock, block until we can aquire it.
        if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  
            // we can still use file_get_contents, which is better than using fread.
            $file = file_get_contents('data.json');
            $accumulatedData = json_decode($file);
            $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
            array_push($accumulatedData, $data);
            $encodedAccumulatedData = json_encode($accumulatedData);
            // Remove existing file contents
            ftruncate($fp, 0); 
            // Write new JSON array to file
            fwrite($fp, $encodedAccumulatedData);
            // release the lock
            flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    
        } else {
            // This should rarely happen since flock will block until it can get a lock.
            // just in case, we should instruct the client to try again later.
            echo "Couldn't get the lock!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be aware of this: "**Warning** On some operating systems flock() is implemented at the process level. When using a multithreaded server API you may not be able to rely on flock() to protect files against other PHP scripts running in parallel threads of the same server instance!" ([source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php))